# Use a parent function inside a child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parent-child

I'm trying to call a parent function with arguments from a child component but I'm not sure exactly how to get it working.  I specifically need to be able to call the parent function from the child within another function, so I tried passing a reference to the function through props but this is not quite right.  The parent class owns a resource that only it should interact with through the specific function call I'm passing.  When done in the following way, I am told the function isn't defined.

```
export class ParentClass extends React.Component {

    ParentFunctionWithArguments(a, b) {
        alert("a is being used by my private resource");
        alert("b is being used by my private resource");
        return true; //some result based on a and b
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildClass>ParentFunctionWithArguments={() => this.ParentFunctionWithArguments()}</ChildClass>
        );
    }
}
```

And

```
export class ChildClass extends React.Component {
    ...
    handleOk = (e) => {
        ...
        if (condition) {
            if (this.props.ParentFunctionWithArguments(a, b)) {}
        }
        ...
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: React is specifically designed not to work like this. Do you have access to redux?

Comment: @JSager I do have access to redux, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was the "bind" function

something like this in the constructor of the parent:

```
export class ParentClass extends React.component {
    constructor() {
        this.ParentFunctionWithArguments = this.ParentFunctionWithArguments.bind(this);
    }
    ... //rest unchanged
}
```

This will allow the child to use the passed in parent function in vanilla react.

Answer (score 0):

```
<childComponent callFromChild={this.parentMethod}/>


//in child component call like below
this.props.callFromChild()
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to the apss the parent function as props to the Child component and not call it within the children

```
export class ParentClass extends React.Component {

    ParentFunctionWithArguments(a, b) {
        alert("a is being used by my private resource");
        alert("b is being used by my private resource");
        return true; //some result based on a and b
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildClass ParentFunctionWithArguments={this.ParentFunctionWithArguments}></ChildClass>
        );
    }
}
```

and simply call it in child like

```
export class ChildClass extends React.Component {

    handleOk = (e) => {
        ...
        if (condition) {
            if (this.props.ParentFunctionWithArguments(a, b)) {}
        }
        ...
    };

    ...
}
```